# populate a form programmatically in drupal

Tags: drupal

I need to populate the form fields programmatically in drupal. I understand that there are 2 approaches:

1. using drupal_execute($form_item,value,$form_state)
2. using form_set_value($form_id,$form_state)

Any working examples would be helpful

I tried the following code which gives the drupal white screen of death

```
function form_validate($form, &$form_state){
  $form_id ='myform';
  $form_state['values'] = array(
    'name' => 'Test',    
  );
  drupal_execute($form_id, $form_state);  // this statement leads to white screen of death
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by populating the form fields? Do you want to change the values of a form field if the form doesn't validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to fill out a field in the form during validation, after the user submits it? I assume this because you are using a validate function.

If so, there is no need for the drupal_execute() function, as the form will be submitted after it passes validation no matter what. I think what you want might be more like this:

```
function form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['values']['name'] = 'test'; 
}
```

Comment: I have a #default_value set for my form. On submit i want to update the user entered value to the textfield. However, the form simply gets populated with the #default_value. How do i override the #default_value?

Comment: You would want to use hook_form_alter() instead of a validate function. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6

Comment: If i use the form_alter, then when the form is called the default_value is never shown. I need to show the default_value first, and overwrite it, only when a user presses the submit  event

Comment: Ahhh. Just leave out the drupal_execute() function. The form will be submitted as soon as the validation function completes.

Comment: Whatever I put in the validation function, it is not able to override the #default_value specified in the form. I want the form to display the #default_value at first. After the user presses the submit event, it should then override this #default_value.

Comment: You can do that. Just leave out the drupal_execute().

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
<?php
$form_id = 'mymodule_form_id';
$rendered_form = drupal_get_form($form_id);
print $rendered_form;
?>
```

See:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/6